# php mysql asc/desc order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, group-by

TABLE:

```
**timeslot**:
----------
id_timeslot   times
1             09:00
2             09:30
3             10:00
4             10:30
5             11:00

**bookslot**
id   id_timeslot     date        b_ref
-------------------------------------------
1    2               2010-02-22  001 
2    3               2010-02-22  001
3    4               2010-02-22  001
4    5               2010-02-22  001
5    2               2010-02-25  002
6    3               2010-02-27  003
7    4               2010-02-27  003
8    5               2010-02-27  003
```

PHP

```
$q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM bookslot  
LEFT JOIN timeslot ON bookslot.id_timeslot = timeslot.id_timeslot   
WHERE bookslot.status = 1 
GROUP BY bookslot.b_ref  
ORDER BY bookslot.date ASC, bookslot.id_timeslot ASC LIMIT 20");
```

HTML RESULT:

```
DATE         TIMES  
2010-02-22   10:30
2010-02-25   09:30
2010-02-27   11:00
```

anyone notice that on the table result. the times is incorrect order?
i changed another way round with ASC / DESC, and still the times showing the last id_timeslot?

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
DATE         TIMES  
2010-02-22   09:30
2010-02-25   09:30
2010-02-27   10:00
```

Comment: It is correct as far as I can see, `2010-02-22 10:30` comes _before_ `2010-02-25 09:30` and `2010-02-27 11:00`.

Comment: Well, I can't find what you're trying to achieve. But `2010-02-27` can't be associated to `10:00` because its timeid is `5` which is `11:00` ...

Comment: You're example is also missing the status column in the bookslot table although you're using it in your WHERE clause. Might that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY bookslot.b_ref` is grouping the records, so you're only seeing the last time in each case.

Try using

```
SELECT date, time, MIN(bookslot.id_timeslot)
FROM bookslot  
LEFT JOIN timeslot ON bookslot.id_timeslot = timeslot.id_timeslot   
WHERE bookslot.status = 1 
GROUP BY bookslot.b_ref  
ORDER BY bookslot.date ASC, bookslot.id_timeslot ASC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1):

While your SQL is syntactically correct but it will produce unexpected results.

Normally, the columns that you `SELECT` must be specified in the `GROUP BY` clause or should be enclosed inside an aggregate function. Otherwise, MySQL will determine, at its own discretion, which records to eliminate in the `GROUP BY` operation. The `ORDER BY` does not matter because it is applied *after* the `GROUP BY` operation. You should better revise your query like this:

```
SELECT b_ref, MIN(ADDTIME(date, times)) AS complete_datetime
FROM bookslot
LEFT JOIN timeslot ON bookslot.id_timeslot = timeslot.id_timeslot
WHERE bookslot.status = 1
GROUP BY bookslot.b_ref
ORDER BY bookslot.date, bookslot.id_timeslot
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the goal appears to be about collecting the earliest timeslots for each bookslot then it's required to narrow the results with `MIN`

```
SELECT b.id, b.id_timeslot, b.date, MIN(`date`) , t.times
FROM bookslot b
LEFT JOIN timeslot t ON b.id_timeslot = t.id_timeslot
GROUP BY b.b_ref
```