# How to get ascending data in php?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I want to get the data from the database in ascending order using the PHP function:

What I tried so far:

```
$query = "select * from posts order by DESC LIMIT 0,1200";

$run = mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
$post_id = $row['un_id'];
$title = $row['post_title'];
$image = $row['post_image']; }
```

Everything seems to work fine until changed the order from DSEC to ASE, and PHP generates the error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...
```

**UPDATE:** I solved it by myself, I updated the question for future visitors

Comment: You need to change it `DESC` to `ASC`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php mysql asc/desc order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078381/php-mysql-asc-desc-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ASE` doesn't exist, it's `ASC` and `DESC`.

Try this request:

```
$query = "select * from posts order by un_id ASC LIMIT 0,1200";
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is `ASC`.

`ASE` does not exist as a keyword

Try this: `$query = "select * from posts order by ASC LIMIT 0,1200";`

Answer (score 0):

Because, `ASE` is not a MySQL keyword.

Try `ASC`:

```
$query = "select * from posts order by ASC LIMIT 0,1200";
```